# extract date only from given date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the best Oracle sql query to extract date?
input entry - 2020-10-14T07:26:32.661Z ,
expected output - 2020-10-14

Comment: What have you tried?  Is the `2020-10-14T07:26:32.661Z` in a database column, or user input to insert/update a database table?  Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `DATE` data type where the time component is midnight then:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
           '2020-10-14T07:26:32.661Z', 
           'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZR'
         )
       ) AS truncated_date
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which (depending on your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`) outputs:

> ```
> | TRUNCATED_DATE      |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2020-10-14 00:00:00 |
> ```

*(Note: a `DATE` data type has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components. Whatever client program you are using to access the database may choose not to show the time component but it will still be there.)*

If you want a `YYYY-MM-DD` formatted string then:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
           '2020-10-14T07:26:32.661Z', 
           'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZR'
         ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD'
       ) AS formatted_date
FROM   DUAL;
```

> ```
> | FORMATTED_DATE |
> | :------------- |
> | 2020-10-14     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7bab928176a72a9c6f781ac17e7580c8)*

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way is probably `trunc()`:

```
select trunc(input_entry)
```

This assumes that `input_entry` is a `date` or `timestamp` value.

EDIT:

If your input is just a string, use string operations:

```
select substr(input_entry, 1, 10)
```

You can also readily cast this to a `date`.

Comment: this query select trunc('2020-10-14T07:26:32.661Z') from dual gives error - ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Ok, my sample input value is 2020-10-14T07:26:32.661Z, any other option?

Comment: The 'trunc' solution is _assuming_ your input "date" is of data type DATE or TIMESTAMP.  If it is actually a character string (that _looks_ like a "date") then the solution will be different.

Comment: @Aadhi . . . As the answer says, this assumes that the input is a date/timestamp.  The answer is actually quite simple if the input is a string.